# RxJava 2 Adapter facory

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

what is the difference between `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()` & `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io())`? Which one should prefer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Difference from the source code**

Both methods returns an instance of synchronous observable, but the `create()` method has no schedulers to operate on by default and the `createWithSchedulers(Scheduler scheduler)` as name suggests, operates on the respective scheduler by default which you mention in method, as per your example it will be `Scheduler.io()`.

**Which one you should use?**

Now this will depend on you, the APIs you directly want to return instance in `Schedulers.io()` or other Schedulers by default then you use the one with schedulers, else you can use the `create()` method and can declare schedulers while getting response every time.

**Note:** I personally use `create()` method as I sometimes mention some other `Schedulers.newThread()` and/or `Schedulers.computation()`

Comment: as per some codepath docs `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()` network calls are synchronous and `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io())` are asynchronous. here is docs: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit#rxjava

Comment: But, isn't it like that if we use that global schedulers and then, in the inner scope we use another kind of scheduler like `newThread` it will be overwritten?(Use the downstream one for the whole chain)

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `Scheduler` to RxJava2CallAdapterFactory, it will add `subscribeOn(scheduler)` to each network request you are making. It is just a convenience method.